# Play video URL in native video app WinRT

Tags: video, windows-runtime, live

How can we open a Video URL in native video application through C# code?

Thanks,
Kavit.

Answer (score 1):

The `Launcher.LanuchUriAsync` will do this for you. You can refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh701484.aspx) for more info on it, but the following should do the trick:-

```
// The URI to launch
string uriToLaunch = @"MICROSOFTVIDEO://www.example.com/myFile.wmv";
var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);

async void DefaultLaunch()
{
   // Launch the URI with a warning prompt
   var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);    
}
```

Comment: Hi Ross, Thanks But when we are providing link to Launcher it is opening only browser (IE).

Comment: I have changed the protocol - this does open windows video, but I don't know if it will correctly launch the application. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Hi Ross, The application opens the link in video app, but that app not able to play it, I think it will play the file which is in video library only. So is there other thing which we have to do?